# Unable to display the same data fetched from mysqli database in 2 times

Tags: php, mysqli

I have fetched an associative array from MySQL database.
When I try to display data using `while` loop for the first time it behaves normally.
But when I try to use the same `while` loop 2 times the first one shows the data but the second one is blank.

My code looks as follows

```
<?php
include 'inc/dbcon.php';
$query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from product");
?>

<select required class="form-control">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    ?>
        <option><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>

<select required class="form-control">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    ?>
        <option><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

**And the out put is like this**

[image: output in browser]

Comment: Just use `foreach` instead of `while`. `foreach` automatically rewinds the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Once a row is fetched from the `$query`, that row is completely removed from the `$query` so trying to fetch that row again will return nothing.

So to reuse the `$query`, you should instead fetch all rows into a variable. Try this

```
<?php

include 'inc/dbcon.php';
$query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from product");
$rows  = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>

<select required class="form-control">
    <?php
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    ?>
        <option><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>

<select required class="form-control">
    <?php
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    ?>
        <option><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>

?>
```